# Extra Request On 301 Moved Permanently Response

Tags: http, jquery, openrasta

I am building a `REST API` method which return `301 Moved Permanently` if my resource identifier gets updated and `204 Modified` in other case.

But after getting `301 Moved Permanently` same request gets fired second time(Different behavior in firefox and chrome).

Is there any way to stop browser from sending a extra request on getting `301 Move Permanently` response from server?